# AssemblyCleanup Not being run.

Tags: c#, ui-automation, vs-unit-testing-framework

I have an issue in where my `[AssemblyCleanup]` method is not being called.

I'm currently building out an automation framework and would like some API calls done before and after my tests. I've since found the assembly initialize/cleanup methods, and they would work perfect for what I need to do. But I am unable to to get the `[AssemblyCleanup]` method to run.

I have a base class that my tests inherent from, and that's where I'd like the `[AssemblyCleanup]` method to be placed.

My class.

```
    [TestClass]
public class TestBaseChrome: WebDriver
{
    public TestContext TestContext { get; set; }

    [TestInitialize]
    public void Initialize()
    {
      //Do Stuff Here for tests
    }

    [TestCleanup]
    public void Cleanup()
    {
        //used for end of test reporting
    }

    [AssemblyCleanup]
    public static void EndOfSuiteActions()
    {            
        //Stuff here when whole test suite finished
    }
}
```

I've seen the examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171531/assemblycleanup-not-firing) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8089025/how-do-i-implement-assemblyinitialize-assemblycleanup-in-my-codeduitest-in-msvs) and show that the `[AssemblyCleanup]` needs to be in a class with the `[TestClass]` attribute. If I place the `[AssemblyCleanup]` in a class with actual tests, it works as intended. But I'd like all my before tests/after tests in once place.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe I've found the answer to my own question.

If a `[TestClass]` inherits from a base class that is in a different assembly of the derived class, the base class `[AssemblyInitialize]` and `[AssemblyCleanup]` methods are not executed.

[Source](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e41d465b-462f-4c4c-a91a-051aba9ccb46/root-parent-base-class-assemblycleanup-not-being-called?forum=vsunittest)

So as my automation tests are in two projects in the solution (one to handle the framework and one to handle the tests) and as the base class is in the framework, but the tests are the other project. I encounter the issue in the link.

Comment: This was my issue exactly. I had my framework and tests in separate projects in my solution, and the SetupTeardown class existed in my framework project. Once I moved the SetupTeardown class into the tests project, the `[AssemblyInitialize]` and `[AssemblyCleanup]` worked like a charm.